# Drawing resizable (not intersecting) polygons

Tags: google-maps, polygon, gpolygon, wikimapia

I have been searching everywhere but I could not find an answer. I 
need to have drawing resizable polygons with mouse interaction but I 
do not want irregular, overlapping or intersecting polygons in the 
end.

Here is a simple example of drawing resizable polygons 
http://www.wolfpil.de/polygon.html

You can easily create & resize polygons which is great. But I need an 
extra functionality to detect intersections and NOT allowing weird 
looking shapes/polygons.
You can see the problem in this video: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zou2jcGM8zw

The only solution for that problem I found at http://www.wikimapia.org. They have added features to handle the problem. 
You can see it in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K7-K0k2D-2A

I spent 3 days trying out to achieve something like this. I have gone 
through wikimapia's javascript code but it is way too complex for me 
to understand.

In sum, it does not have to look as fancy as as wikimapia's. I just 
need resizable polygons which do NOT intersect while resizing or 
adding new points to it. Can you give me any suggestions how to 
achieve that?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many points that you allow, a naive, simple `O(N^2)` line intersection algorithm suffices. Algorithmically this is not the best solution, but for starting out it's the most accessible for a beginner in computational geometry.

For starter, see [Wikipedia article on line segment intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment_intersection). [One of its links](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/lineline2d/) has an easy to understand explanation on how to compute the intersection point of two line segments.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it helps me to understand that this problem is far more complex than I think.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a complete answer, note that the example you supplied appears to be using the [Geometry Controls](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geometrycontrols/examples/test.html) from the [GMaps Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/), which is an open source project hosted on Google Code.

You can check [the full source code in the Google Code browser](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-utility-library-dev/source/browse/trunk/geometrycontrols/src/polygoncontrol.js).

[image: Google's Geometry Controls]

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I have gone through that example but it does not help me out with what I need exactly.