# How to traverse an array of latitude and longitude in JavaScript in an order?

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates

I have an array of point like

```
 aa = [ [1,2], [1,2],[2,1], [2,2], [3,1], [3,2] ]
```

How can I traverse through those point in an order. Fiddle here:

[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitrox/aan3G/)

I took some idea from [Sort latitude and longitude coordinates into clockwise ordered quadrilateral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855189/sort-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-into-clockwise-ordered-quadrilateral/2863378#comment36032576_2863378) but didn't work out

update: I think it would make sense if we add more description like traverse from A to F, with east to west direction, like shown in fig below. With this case I think we could sort  the following way (noted in fig)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend ordering the points first.
Take the smallest as a point of reference then use the distance from the reference to sort.

```
    var upper = upperLeft(points);
    points.sort(function (point) {
        return -point.distance(upper);
    });
    console.log(points);
```

This will invert them in sequence.
Remove the - sign to start from F to A

Answer (score 0):

If you read the answer carefully, they admit that it's not an optimal path. It's simply following an arc from the selected point, and selecting in order anything that lies between the arc and the point. So imagine a pendulum swinging, and anything the bar of the pendulum touches is selected in that order.

This is not a quadrilateral path.

To make a quadrilateral path it may work if instead of calling the method from point A to all other points, you call it recursively selecting only the first point.

Basically, if instead of going from point A to all points, you use the algorithm in recursion, and after the first point is selected, you call it again with the new point. So each point is the clockwise most away from the previous point. Then after every call, you remove the selected points from the list of available points.

However, that will only work if the problem is simple. Meaning you won't have to indent your shape to select all points. So if you have points that is within the interior of a shape of outermost points, the solution will be drastically more complex.

It would require picking a point of indent, and then reversing the algorithm. Then doing that recursively.